# LAMP mysql 5.5.46 shows innodb SUPPORT = NO

Tags: mysql-workbench

Trying to install Moodle2.9 STABLE  on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ,
it shows MYSQL should support innodb

while checking found innodb disabled and SUPPORT = NO 
tried to edit /etc/mysql/my.cnf but no success.

phpmyadmin shows MYSQL 5.5.46 does not support innodb , which is strange

need your expert suggestion